# C++ classes refer to each other ( => error + field '...' has incomplete type)

Tags: c++, class

Classes in my application work like this: `Creature` has few fields with `Action`s. When these `Action`s must be run `Creature` calls `someActionField->do(this)`. Action has method `viod do(Creature* cr)` and all information about what to do with this `Creature`.

So, Creature must have `Action` field and know that `Action` has `do` method. Action must know that `Creature` has such fields like: Will, HP, etc...

I've got

creature.h

```
 #include "effect.h"
 #include "heedupdate.h"

 namespace Core
 {

 class Action;

 class Creature : public NeedUpDate
 {
 public:
     virtual ~Creature();
     int HP;
     Action onHit;
     Action onDie;
// ...


 };

 }
#endif
```

And action.h

```
#include "creature.h"

namespace Core
{


class Action
{
public:
Action();
virtual void _do(Creature* cr);
virtual ~Action();
};
```

But in this case field `` `onDie' has incomplete type `` error appears. If I include action.h into creature.h - I use files 'before each other'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You `Creature` class has members of type `Action`. The compiler needs to know the full definition of the `Action` class to compile that - an incomplete type as produced with a forward declaration is not enough.

The `Action` class only requires a *pointer* to a `Creature` object in that header. In that case, the compiler only needs to know that `Creature` will be defined at some point.

In your specific case, you could get away with inverting the order in which you declare your classes.

(i.e. forward-declare `Creature` in `action.h`, and include `action.h` in `creature.h`)

Comment: Yes, I caught that just a second before you posted that. :) Thanks, anyway.

Comment: The part about references is *wrong*. References and pointer need the same knowledge. Also, there is no reference involved in the OP's code, only full objects.

Comment: @Xeo: that was very poorly worded indeed.

Answer (score 3):

in action.h put `class Creature;` and in the other one `#include "action.h"`

For pointers you don't need complete definition because it's just a pointer and the compiler can generate "code" for it. If you use a simple class/struct the compiler has to have knowledge of the type because it needs to know how big it is.

Answer (score 3):

When you ***forward declare*** a type, all the compiler know is that this type exists; it knows nothing about its size, members, or methods, hence it is called an ***Incomplete Type***

You cannot use an incomplete type to declare a member(because compile needs to know the size of the type while declaring it) and hence you get the error.

You don't need to #include "creature.h" in action.h but you just need to forward declare class Creature. You do need to #include "action.h" in creature.h

Your header files should have the following construct:

**creature.h**

```
#include "effect.h"
#include "action.h"
#include "heedupdate.h"
```

**action.h**

```
class creature;
```

This makes use of two rules:

- One can Declare functions or methods which accepts/return incomplete types:

`action.h` only declares a function which accepts an Incomplete type(Creature)

- One cannot declare a member to an incomplete type.

`creature.h`has to include `action.h` because it declares a member of type `Action`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to #include "creature.h" in action.h. All you need is a forward declaration of class Creature. You do need to #include "action.h" in creature.h because onHit and onDie are instances of Action.

Answer (score 0):

Use references, or pointers :

```
     #include "effect.h"
     #include "heedupdate.h"

     namespace Core
     {

     class Action;

     class Creature : public NeedUpDate
     {
     public:
         virtual ~Creature();
         int HP;
         Action & onHit;
         Action & onDie;
    // ...


     };

     }

#endif
```

This way you can break dependencies and not need a fully declared `Action` class